# How to access logged in user data, in a layout. (CakePHP 3)

Tags: authentication, layout, cakephp-3.0

I have a web app programmed in **cakephp 3**.

I want to have a layout that shows *logged in user first & last name*. like something in facebook main page. that you can click and go to your page.
I want to have this feature in every page, so I decided to use layouts.

my `Users` table is like:

| **id** | **username** | **password** | **email** | **first_name** | **last_name** | **created** | **modified** |

I use Authentication Component like this:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Authentication Error'
    ]);
```

**How can I load user first name and last name in a layout?**

Comment: @ndm, in that question he asked about showing in view, but I want this information in a layout. please pay attention to the question.

Comment: Layouts are part of the the view layer, they are nothing more than global view (wrapper) templates. Please pay attention to the concepts of the software that you are using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it by using **`Session`**. like:

```
$user = "";
$loguser = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
if(!empty($loguser)){
    $user = $loguser['first_name']." ".$loguser['last_name'];
}
```

**UPDATE (8/23/2015) :**

as recently cakephp says that SessionHelper is deprecated, you should use `request->session()` instead.

```
$loguser = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
if(!$loguser) {
    $user = $loguser['first_name'].' '.$loguser['last_name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It works, but I am getting a deprecation warning: `SessionHelper has been deprecated. Use request->session() instead.`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your variables through controller to views by:

```
$this->set('user','users_data');
```

and then pass this to the layout:

```
$this->assign('user',$user);
```

and show it in the layout by:

```
$this->fetch('user');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the data from the controller to the view environment. 
I've found the best way to do this globally is to put the set() statement in AppController::beforeRender-

```
   // make logged in user's first name available to the view (mainly for menu)
  $name="(none)";
  if($this->Auth->user()) {
    $name = $this->Auth->user("first_name");
  }

  $this->set("user_first_name", $name);
```

Just please make sure not to put any sensitive data there, eg password, as a bug at the template level could potentially expose it.